# How to Calculate and Get Total Values According to Quantity in Excel

Tags: excel

How do I create the formula that sums each item (unit) by multiplying them by the quantity and resulting in the total value of all items in column `C7` in Excel Plan..

Example:

- `C2` * `A2` +
- `C3` * `A3` +
- `C4` * `A4` +
- `C5` * `A5` = **$2104,3** (according to the values of each item, remembering are different values!)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5,C2:C5)
```